# ASP.NET get variables from Crystal Report not transferring properly to external application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that redirects to another application URL and includes get variables in the link. For some reason those variables disappear when the page loads in the second application, and I'm not sure why.

When I view the source of the Crystal Report output, here is an example link:

```
<a href="javascript:parent.bobj.event.publish(&#39;hyperlinkClicked&#39;,&#39;CrystalReportViewer1__UI&#39;,&#39;target=_self&amp;url=%2fintranet%2fAPI_PriceInc_Ltr%2fStart.aspx%3fslmno%3d1007%26cusno%3d2455%26venno%3d22364%26cutoff%3d08%2f01%2f2013%26increase%3d.01%26shipaddr%3d0%26effective%3d08%2f05%2f2013%26slmname%3dXXX#39;)" target="_self" class="fcb0e6b53e-82c1-4e73-b9a7-b7cebfc74add-5">GLASS&nbsp;BLOWING&nbsp;SHOP</a>
```

When I plug this into an html decoder to make sure it's correct, I get this result:

```
javascript:parent.bobj.event.publish('hyperlinkClicked','CrystalReportViewer1__UI','target=_self&url=/intranet/API_PriceInc_Ltr/Start.aspx?slmno=ZZZ&cusno=7597&venno=50065&cutoff=08/01/2013&increase=.01&shipaddr=773&effective=08/05/2013&slmname=XXXX')
```

The above string works perfectly when I plug it into the web page URL bar manually(adding the server IP, of course.) However, when I click on the link from the Crystal Report, I get this instead:

```
http://SERVER-IP/intranet/API_PriceInc_Ltr/Start.aspx?slmno
```

For some reason everything after the name of the first variable gets cut off. Any suggestions as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a known bug that was documented ~3 years ago on the SAP webpage. Their support said it was resolved with an update, the poster came back stating that the issue was still present, and then there was never another response.

Here is the initial thread documenting the issue: http://scn.sap.com/message/9553393

Here is my thread bringing the issue back up (hopefully to resolution): http://scn.sap.com/thread/3416821

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, upgrading from Crystal Report 9 to 13 and .NET 1.1 to 4.0.

My link is build by a format formula (format editor, tab "hyperlink").

**Solution: I had to change something in the formula and save ist again.**

You don't need to change something specific. Add a blank or anything. Just re-save the formula with the Crystal Report 13 editor.

Possible you first have to upgrade your Crystal Report to the newest servicepack, like mentioned in the links from Ben's answer. Not sure because I found the solution with re-saving after I upgraded.

Comment: What did you have to change in the formula?

Comment: Nothing specific. Point is I had to re-save the formula with the new CR editor. I think something with the upgrade of formulas went wrong and re-saving fixed it.